# Repeated values are stored when copied to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like x,

```
> x
 x1 x2 x3 x4
 1  3  5  7
 3  4  7  2 
 1  7  8  7
 2  3  7  4
```

I want to change each row based on some calculations. The resulting rows are not of same size. say, I have to want to copy a row of length 2,

```
y <- c(1,2)
x[1,] <- y
```

Then the values stored repeatedly in x,

```
> x
 x1 x2 x3 x4
 1  2  1  2
 3  4  7  2 
 1  7  8  7
 2  3  7  4
```

But my output should be,

```
> x
 x1 x2 x3 x4
 1  2  NA  NA
 3  4  7  2 
 1  7  8  7
 2  3  7  4
```

How to do this?

Comment: How about `y <- c(1, 2, NA, NA)`?

Comment: you could check out the function `rbindlist` from the package `data.table` which has an argument `fill`which you could set to `fill = TRUE` to fill the empty columns of the row you want to insert with NAs

Comment: That function dint work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clever solution came to mind, so here is a small function which pads y with NA. Using the padded y gives the intended behavior.

```
pad_with_NA <- function(y, dim_x) {
  if(length(y)<dim_x) {
    y <- c(y, rep(NA, dim_x-length(y)))
  }
  y
}

x[1,] <- pad_with_NA(y, dim(x)[2])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could pad the NAs based on the number of columns of 'x' by assigning `length` of 'y' to `ncol(x)`.  If the `length` of 'y' is less than `ncol(x)`, it will pad the additional elements with `NA`.

```
  x[1,] <- `length<-`(y, ncol(x))
  x
  #  x1 x2 x3 x4
  #1  1  2 NA NA
  #2  3  4  7  2
  #3  1  7  8  7
  #4  2  3  7  4
```

Just for easier understanding, this is similar to the two step process @mpalanco mentioned in the comments, i..e first we change the `length(y)` to be the `length(x)` (or `ncol(x)` - in a 'data.frame', `length` and `ncol` are the same) to pad NAs and then replace the first row value of 'x' with that of 'y'.

```
  length(y) <- length(x)
  x[1,] <- y
```

#### data

```
 x <- structure(list(x1 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), x2 = c(3L, 4L, 7L, 3L), 
 x3 = c(5L, 7L, 8L, 7L), x4 = c(7L, 2L, 7L, 4L)), .Names = c("x1", 
 "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This is a really nice hack.

Comment: @antoine-sac Thanks, this I use it regularly when we deal with `list` with unequal lengths for list elements

Comment: @akrun Just for me to undestand what you're doing is this? `length(y) <- length(x); x[1,] <- y`